# Error handling for PHP under IIS: web.config still does not redirect when non-existing page is required

Tags: php, iis-8

I am using PHP under IIS. I want to change the error behavior and redirect to some page when user requests for non existing page. This is the config I created, however it returns me 500.19 error message when I request for a non-existing url:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" errorMode="custom">
            <remove statusCode="404" />
            <error statusCode="404" path="index.php" responseMode="Redirect" />

            <remove statusCode="500" />
            <error statusCode="500" path="index.php" responseMode="Redirect" />
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

What should I change to make it to redirect to index.php ?